# javaFX 2.0 XYChart and CSS

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX 2.0 and to do practice I have followed the Oracle example about Line Chart (Stock Monitoring)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI

Now I would like to ad a CSS class in the same package to modify Stroke, color, etc but I can't succed.

Searching here on StackOverflow I have found

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("linechart.css").toExternalForm());
```

but I still get errors

```
Exception in Application start method Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
```

My java class name is JavaFXApplication2 and CSS class name is linechart.css

Would someone be so kind to explain me where I am wrong?

There is another nice tutorial about the CSS use with Stock Monitoring example here
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/charts/css-styles.htm

but I do not know how to add the CSS examples to the java class

Thanks

Comment: Stack:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javafxapplication2.JavaFXApplication2.start(JavaFXApplication2.java:75)
Where line 75 is the 

scene.getStylesheets(). etc statement

Comment: At that line `NullPointerException` may occur if the `scene` is not yet initialized or if the `linechart.css` file does not exist. Double check the CSS file name and its location in a package. Alternatively you can post your `start(Stage primaryStage)` method in `JavaFXApplication2` here.

Comment: public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
       stage.setTitle("Lines plot");
       
       final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
       final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
       final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 23));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 14));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 15));

Comment: Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);
stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

Comment: It seems ok. I suspect that the css file is not being copied to the folder where the java files are compiled. Are you using an IDE? Can you add this line to your app  `System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource(".").toExternalForm());` and copy the css file to the folder path printed by this line.

Comment: Uluk, many many thanks!
I am using NetBeans and you've guessed where the error was: I have my css file in scr folder, while your print statements gave me
Java/JavaFXApplication2/build/classes/javafxapplication2/
Once copied the css file in this classes folder I finally can see css properties added to the line graph.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you solved it.

Comment: Uluk can you, please, post your answer as "answer" so this question wouldn't stay unanswered from stackoverflow's point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the css file is not being copied to the folder where the java files are compiled. Are you using an IDE? Can you add this line to your app `System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource(".").toExternalForm());`
and copy the css file to the folder path printed by this line.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the project or copy the css file to the build path.If you using netbeans,you must build the project once after new resource file added.